# How to transfer date from form to django code (datepicker form to value (htmx))?

Tags: python, html, django, htmx

Good good evening!

I have a standard datepicker form.
I'm trying to figure out how to take the start and end date values. At least one date value from the form to use in various Python calculations.
I have a data table where the data is sorted by date. And I need to take only certain rows from the given table. Having values in code.
I need to somehow capture the date value and send this value to the code.
Maybe there are some modern methods for taking data from an html or htmx form?

I have been thinking for a long time how and what can be done in order to take data from a form and put it into code for some kind of calculation processing.

I would be very grateful for any hints, help.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
 
class Offer(models.Model):
    expiration_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Offer
 
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
 
class OfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
    fields = fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
            'expiration_date': DateInput(),
        }
```

template

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}  
{{ form|crispy }}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare this in views.py file like this:

```
def your_view_function(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OfferForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        # Do something with the start and end dates here
else:
    form = OfferForm()
return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

You can then use these date values to filter the rows in your data table using a queryset like Offer.objects.filter(expiration_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).

Comment: Thank you so much.
You are saving me.
Can you kindly suggest how to build an html form to take a start and end date from it.
How to connect them with the form and view.
I'm still a beginner, but this functionality is extremely important to me now. I would really appreciate any information.
Thank you very much.